# Paste image into a cell

Tags: google-sheets

Pasting an image into Google Sheets puts it onto the sheet. I would like to paste the image directly into a cell. You can do this by using the menu Insert > Image> Image In Cell.

I would also be happy if I could move an image pasted onto the sheet into a cell. Any ideas short of saving my screenshots to disk and then uploading it through the aforementioned menu?

Comment: Interestingly you can double click a cell so the cursor appears. Paste an image into the cell seeing it appear. Navigate away from the cell and the image disappears 

Comment: yeah, the first image worked for me and remains in the first cell, but then for all other attempts, what happened for you happened for me too.

Comment: I couldn't get images to paste anymore into my original Google Sheet, but I created a totally new Google Sheet (separate file) and was able to paste them in there. Then I clicked the sheet tab at the bottom of the screen and used the "Copy To" feature to copy my sheet into my original doc.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can simply copy and paste into the sheets, there is no need to use the Insert Menu you have described. Follow these steps to add an image to a cell in a Google Sheet:

1. Copy the Image from your source (eg take a screenshot with snipping
   tool)
2. Open the Sheet & Paste the Image from your clipboard
3. Select the Cell you would like to add the Image too
4. Select the Picture
5. Click the Triple dot in the top right of the picture (you can resize the
   picture to be bigger so you can easily see this menu)

[image: Open Image Menu]

6. In the Menu select "Put Image in selected Cell"

[image: Put Image in selected Cell]

Comment: That's a weird interface, but easy once you get the hang of it. Thanks, @Cassidy, for a clear explanation!

Comment: I wonder why this worked only for my first image. Then for subsequent images, no images would get pasted from the clipboard. See also comments above.